# Android: print data on barcode scanner builder window

Tags: java, android, database, barcode

Ok, so i need to display some of my product's database data on the scanner builder window(as shown in the image) when this product gets scanned. [Scanner window results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRLtU.jpg)

As you can see in the image, the barcode scanner is displayed, my question is: is it possible to print in this windows some other data except from the product's barcode? if yes how should i move?

this is my windows builder code

```
public void handleResult(Result result) {
         //myResult= barcode text
         myResult = result.getText();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(addquantityactivity.this);
                updateData();
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Visit(if url)", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myResult));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
        alert1.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see where it says builder.setMessage(result.getText()); <--?

This is where you'd set the result. At the moment you're just putting in the result text which is the number. If you want something more, there is where you would put it.

EDIT:

I'm terrible at writing answers. The method you are using is defined [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder#setMessage(java.lang.CharSequence)). It takes in a Character Sequence and will display it. Or it can take in an Int and show that.

EDIT2:

As an example of concatenating the barcode with some other information I would do this:

```
String myMessage = result.getText() + " and some other amazing information about this barcode";

builder.setMessage(myMessage);
```

Comment: perfect..every message will appear in a new line?

Comment: I don't imagine so, I believe it would just replace whatever you have. Since this is Java you could use a Stringbuilder (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build a string from a bunch of input that can include New Lines.

Comment: the output on the comment you made, it just replaces the old line, which is the barcode..do you know instead of ```builder.setMessage``` if there is something to append in this builder? and not to overrite as it does..ps: im also terrible at writing english sentences;p

Comment: It is perfectly ok. People who only speak english are terrible at writing sentences. Just like I'm still learning how to write answers.